# How can I add a contact I do not own to the Opportunity Contact Role

Tags: professional-edition, lookup-filter, spring14, opportunitycontactrole, userrecordaccess

After configuring Opportunity Contact Role related list, Users can only choose contact they own although they have read access to other contacts.

I need them to be able to select any contacts.

What I checked:
 -Sharing settings on Contacts = Public Read/Write, 
 -Sharing settings on Opportunity = Public Read/Write
 -Using Salesforce Professional Edition

Any ideas are most welcome. Tks

Comment: how about create a sharing rule to share the contacts

Comment: @Baskaran Tried creating a sharing rule without success:  Contact: owned by members of Entire Organization
Share with Entire Organization
Access : Read Write.  I feel that the rule is somehow redundant since the sharing is already public read/write...

Comment: Correct. i agree with you Alexander.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contactroles.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution found with Salesforce Support:

> The reason why you are unable to add this contact in opportunity
> contact roles is because the contact record doesn't have an Account
> Name associated to it. Please know that contacts that are not linked
> to an Account (personal contacts) are always private, regardless of
> your organization's sharing model. Only the owner of the contact,
> System Administrators, or users with View All for Contacts, or View
> All Data, can view it.  However, users with View All or View All Data,
> but lacking Modify All for Contacts, or Modify All Data, cannot edit
> the Private Contact record.
>
> Sharing rules do not apply to private contacts. If your organization
> uses divisions, private contacts always belong to the global division.
>
> To make it visible in lookup search results, make sure you meet
> following conditions:
> -You are the owner of the contact. OR
> -Enhanced Lookups is enabled for Contact ( => Setup | Customize | Search | Search Settings)
>
> For more information, you may visit the Help and Training article link
> below:
>
> https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Private-contacts-do-not-show-in-lookup-search-results&language=en_US